# Cubic root of $3 \times 3$ identity matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Is there a real $3 \times 3$ matrix $A$, such that: $A^3 = I_3$ and has at most one zero entry?  If so, how can I find it?

Comment: Have you tried undiagonalizing the cube root with three distinct eigenvalues?

Answer (score 1):

There are many. For example, take a rotation matrix by angle $2\pi/3$ around an arbitrary axis. You can find the expression [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Rotation_matrix_from_axis_and_angle). If you cube it, you get a rotation by $2\pi$ around that axis, which is the identity.

Answer (score 1):

Since $A=(a_{ij})_{(3\times3)}$ satisfies $A^3-I=0$, so the characteristic equation of $A$ is $x^3-1=0$

Now $x^3-1=0\implies (x-1)(x^2+x+1)=0\implies\begin{vmatrix} 
1-x & 0 & 0 \\
0 & -x & 1 \\ 
0 & -1 & -1-x
\end{vmatrix}=0$

Construct a matrix $A=\begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & -1 & -1 
\end{pmatrix}$

Clearly $(x-1)(x^2+x+1)=0$ is  characteristic equation of $A$ and so it also satisfy $A^3-I=0$

Comment: I m not understanding how you wrote that determinant just after cayley theorem.

Comment: @Vineet Kumar  Is it not true? What I do is nothing but to adjust a polynomial in terms of determinant value.

Comment: I just want to know how did you find that particular adjustment.  In case the matrix is large say $5 \times 5$ then it would not be that straightforward to find that particular adjustment. 
Nevertheless, your solution is correct I just want to learn how to organize the matrix in that way. :-)

Comment: Look since $(x-1)$ is a factor of the  characteristic polynomial , so for the $3 \times 3$ matrix, I take a row/column containing one element as $(x-1)$ and the remaining elements are $0$. Now for the remaining part I adjust a $2 \times 2$ matrix whose determinant gives the value $(x^2+x+1)$. If the characteristic polynomial is irreducible or containing an irreducible part of degree more than $2$ then it is difficult to take such choice.